# How to use 'AddServiceEndpoint' address parameter in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, endpoint

I have a question regarding the usage of 'AddServiceEndpoint' method of the 'ServiceHost' class.
It seems that adding a value to the 'address' parameter part of this method does not work.

Please refer to the code excerpt below:

```
Uri httpUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8090/DuplexServer/SimpleCalculator");
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(DuplexServer.ICalculatorDuplex), new WSDualHttpBinding(), "");
```

Here, in order to test, I can access this URL through a Web Browser:
`http://localhost:8090/DuplexServer/SimpleCalculator` and a webpage successfully shows.

However, if I implemented it this way instead:

```
Uri httpUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8090/DuplexServer/");
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(DuplexServer.ICalculatorDuplex), new WSDualHttpBinding(), "SimpleCalculator");
```

When I access : `http://localhost:8090/DuplexServer/SimpleCalculator`, a blank page appears.

The method is being run in the host project's file, which is a console app.
Whole code as requested:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create a URI to serve as the base address
            Uri httpUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8090/DuplexServer/SimpleCalculator");

            //Create ServiceHost
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(DuplexServer.CalculatorService), httpUrl);

            //Add a service endpoint
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(DuplexServer.ICalculatorDuplex), new WSDualHttpBinding(), "");

            //Enable metadata exchange
            /*
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            */

            //Start the Service
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Service is host at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Host is running... Press <Enter> key to stop");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I would like to know the proper way to use the 'Address' parameter of this method.

Thanks.

Comment: The code excerpts are incomplete - it's not clear what are you doing with your httpUrl

Comment: Hi @MaksimSatsikau , the other code excerpts are just merely to start the service host. Ive just added the whole method for your reference. Thanks.

Comment: See the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731820/empty-response-on-wcf-web-service-with-custom-addresses-on-endpoints

Comment: Hi @MaksimSatsikau, so in conclusion, the reason why I wasn't able to directly access those endpoints through the browser is because endpoint address only accepts SOAP requests? Thanks.